# JavaScript 'MAX SAFE INTEGER' | Large numbers (digits > 16) gets replaced by 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a POST request in my angular App where a transaction ID is to be send as Number(not string). But when the length of number is greater than 17 then the digits after 17th position is changed to 0.

This issue is not there when the type is text. But I have the requirement to send it as number. I could see the same result in AngularJS also.

HTML

```
 <input type="number" name="uppTransactionId" formControlName="uppTransactionId" />
```

TS

```
 uppTransactionIdFC: FormControl;
this.uppTransactionIdFC = new FormControl();
this.form= new FormGroup({      
      uppTransactionId: this.uppTransactionIdFC     
    });
```

console output for

```
this.uppTransactionIdFC.value
```

always appends the results with 0 at end.

I want to to get number with length >=20 in angular.
e.g. 1234567891234567833

Comment: How about pasting actual console output and raw request (or response) body?

Comment: I don't think you can send those as numbers. If i'm not wrong, numbers are represented on 64 bits, but only the 52 bits are used for the value. If you convert your number to binary, it needs 61 bits.

Comment: my expected outout is 1234567891234567833 but i get 1234567891234568000

Comment: @Bogdan Is there any solution for it, like in Java we have multiple datatypes to handle large numbers

Comment: @Ismail. Yes, that is the problem, what i said above. 1234567891234568000 
 = 100011000101101010100111100100110111010111100001000 which is 52 bits long. It will convert your number to the largest closest value.  Also, why can't you use string for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript the [*max safe integer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is `2^53 - 1` or `9007199254740991` i.e. a number with 16 digits (in base 10)

You cannot reliably represent an integer larger than that in JavaScript using the usual `Number` type.

You can use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to represent arbitrarily large numbers, but browser support is lacking in Safari and (duh) Internet Explorer.

You could also choose to represent transaction ids as a string. I reckon you won't do much Number-related operations on them anyways (like addition, subtraction)